# Need explanation of function which tests all chars in a string for uniqueness

Tags: java

How does this solution to the question "Implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters" work ?

```
public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
    int checker = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        int val = str.charAt(i) - ‘a’;
        if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) return false;
        checker |= (1 << val);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`checker` is a packed array of 26 bits, stored as an `int`. bit 0 = 'a', bit 1 = 'b', bit 2 = 'c', etc. Each character in the input string is tested to see if it has already been seen in the string, and if it has then the function returns false, otherwise the corresponding bit it set and the next character is tested. If the end of the string is reached without any matches then the function returns true.

Note that this functions fails if the string contains anything other than lower case alphabetic characters.